# Updating Maven relativePath based on absolute path values

Tags: maven

I have such directory structure in my machine:

```
MyProjects
|
+-- MainProject
|   |
|   +-- pom.xml
|
+-- AdditionProjects
    |
    +-- AdditionProject1
        |
        +-- pom.xml
```

And I write such code into `AdditionProject1/pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <relativePath>../../MainProject/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>add_project_1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

But when I run this code on a build machine I have a little bit different directory structure:

```
SomeBuildProjects
|
+-- MainProject
|   |
|   +-- pom.xml
|
+-- AdditionProject1
    |
    +-- pom.xml
```

And I need replace relative path `../../MainProject/pom.xml` to `../MainProject/pom.xml`.

In a build machine I have properties that contains absolute path to `MainProject` and to `AdditionProject1`.

**How I can get relative path from absolute path using Maven?**

For example, in Ant I can write `JavaScript` code into `<script></script>` and can process values of properties. *Maybe Maven have something same?*

**Maybe I can use absolute path instead relative path in `<parent></parent>`?**

Comment: Why do you have different paths on a build system? Haven't you checked in the structure in your version control?

Comment: It possible, but it can broke other projects. Such structure is more useful for us...

Comment: you really didn't answer the question? Apart from that why would this could break other projects?..Furthermore your structure of your projects is not what Maven expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the following layout for the project:

```
MyProjects (pom.xml)
|
+-- MainProject
|   |
|   +-- pom.xml
|
+-- AdditionProjects (pom.xml)
    |
    +-- AdditionProject1
        |
        +-- pom.xml
```

By using this layout you have to give on the root folder the following:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WhatEvery</groupId>
  <artifactId>root</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
   <module>MainProject</module>
   <module>AdditionProjects</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Within the sub module you can use the parent like this:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>WhatEvery</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>MainProject</artifactId>
  ...    
</project>
```

And finally the AdditionProjects:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>WhatEvery</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>AdditionProjects</artifactId>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
   <module>AdditionProject1</module>
  </modules>

  ...    
</project>
```

And in the AdditionProject1 project you have the following in your pom:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>WhatEvery</groupId>
    <artifactId>AdditionProjects</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>AdditionProject1</artifactId>
  ...    
</project>
```

By using the correct strucutre which should be of course checked in into version control the same way you don't need to set the `relativePath` element and of course makes your pom's simpler. Apart from that if you have checked in that into version control it doesn't matter if your build server checks out the same structure. You don't need to change anything.

Comment: Probably impossible to use properties into `relativePath`. So, your suggestion is a single solution. Thanks!